# Kubuntu stuck on black screen on boot after trying to update to 23.04 Lunar Lobster

Tags: boot, kubuntu, apport

I tried updating my Kubuntu system from 22. to 23.04 today and my system didn't go through with the updates. After this, i deleted some third-party files I didn't really need (open-office, teams) and updated again which seemed to work. After restarting my system though, my Kubuntu wouldn't boot and showed an error: [ERROR] Failed to start apport-autoreport.service

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUzDi.jpg)

I later booted into system to find that the error message didn't appear but I was still stuck on the black screen. How do I fix this? I have importanr data on my drive and I've been trying to get into my login screen for the past day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved. I booted it up on Recovery mode and updated my system thru recovery mode.

Comment: What does updated your system mean exactly? What steps?

Answer (score 0):

okay once you boot in try swtiching to a different TTY.`CTRL+ALT+F4` should work fine. If not try a different F key.This still drop you into a Command shell. Use you're normal user and password to login.

Run `sudo apt update` to make sure your repos are up to date.

Try running this to ensure you have all the drivers you need installed. `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`